# Synchronize time zones

Tags: java, spring, synchronization, timezone

I have a spring-web-mobile based application which needs to synchronize the instant when an event is produced regardless the time zone of both parts of the application. For instance: A client makes a request in China and the server lies in USA. Is there any suggestion to synchronize both time zones?

Comment: have you considered using UTC times across your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTC time zones across your application. It won't matter from where the request is coming from.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I've successfully synchronize both of the applications